# Apt Update Error (skipping acquire of configured)

Tags: apt, updates, repository

I know there is a similar question on AQ, which I have looked at for days. It doesn't apply to me because it was about Google Chrome, mine is not. I can't amend solutions to work for me because I don't really understand them and/or it doesn't work.

I am hoping somebody will know what to do about this:

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l05X.png)

[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpnN1.png)

Written example:

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/binary-i396/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i396'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/binary-i1386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i1386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i396/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i396'
```

I don't know what to do, I haven't installed many programs and the ones I have and no longer wanted, I had completely purged and removed them along with their dependencies.

Thank you for any help.

EDIT: as per Pilot6's request, here is the output:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412)]/ zesty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty main restricted
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates main restricted
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty universe
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates universe
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security multiverse
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ zesty parnet partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ zesty parnet
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ zesty partner
# deb http://archive.canonical.com zesty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com zesty partner
```

EDIT:

```
~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
i1386
i396
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` terminal command. You probably made edits to that file and added `i396` and `i1386` that is crap.

Comment: @Pilot6 Forgive me noob-ness. I have done as you've asked but don't know how to properly format it into the body. The first line gets formatted in backticks or blocks, but the rest is big and bold. I can't add more links to images. I will try this: (https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GB73qy8.png) and (https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GB73EAJ.png). I hope the brackets have formatted the links.

Comment: @CaptainFudge Select the text and press `{}` button.

Comment: @ADDB It is not a "foreign arch" it is a typo.

Comment: It looks like all typos in the file are commented out. Check the foreign architectures. You entered some crap somewhere.

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm not sure I understand, but is the current edit what you're after?

Comment: Yes, I needed that. Hold on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i1386
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i396
```

These architectures don't exist. You made some typos when running some commands. Be more careful.